# Kendo Scatter Chart Dock Tooltip

Tags: c#, jquery, kendo-ui

I'm wondering if there is a way where we can dock the tooltip in a Kendo Scatter Chart? Essentially, I want to put a hyperlink in the tooltip that makes the user navigate to another system by passing the parameters from the Data Point.

Does anyone know if this is possible? I haven't found any examples on Telerik's [website](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scatter-charts/scatter-line). For reference, this is what I'm using:

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tooltip template property

```
tooltip: {
     visible: true,
     template: "<a href='/yourUrlandParam'>${value}</a>"
 }
```